# Is there a way to use emmet in *.gohtml template files in GoLand IDE

Tags: go, emmet, goland

I am using JetBrains GoLand IDE, and I want to use emmet to generate html inside of *.gohtml template files. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that once enabled, the functionality should work in .gohtml files as well. Here's a guide on how to turn this on - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/settings-emmet.html#settings_emmet_html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).